# Creating a new div every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want divs with circles to be created and appear on my page

I made a create function where I randomly choose a color and add a `circle` class which gives the shape of a circle

But now I have them all created together, and the quantity is what I indicate

How can I make these divs create themselves, let's say every 3 seconds, and the number of them on the page is almost unlimited?

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
    
createDiv('first');
createDiv('second');
createDiv('third');
createDiv('fourth');
createDiv('fifth');
createDiv('sixth');
createDiv('seventh');
createDiv('eighth');
createDiv('ninth');
createDiv('tenth');
createDiv('eleventh');
createDiv('twelfth');
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) to run the script every three seconds.  Since your `id` is required, the function I'm running every three seconds below also iterates an `i` var to leverage and keep unique ids:

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
    
let i = 0;

const threeSeconds = 3000;

setInterval(() => {
  i += 1;
  createDiv(`div-${i}`)
}, threeSeconds);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only one line of code in your JavaScript file, by using `setIterval` timer, and `Date.now()` to generate unique `id` each time:

```js
setInterval(() => createDiv(Date.now()), 3000);
```

---

**Working example:**

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

setInterval(() => createDiv(Date.now()), 3000);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: FYI, The approach you are leveraging here is making several `<div>` elements with the duplicate `id` of `"undefined"`, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: You are completely right. I updated my answer to generate unique `id` each time. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

setInterval("wrapper()", 3000);

let cnt = 0;
function wrapper(){
  let id = 'id' + cnt
  createDiv(id)
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a timeout function, you may need a way to opt out as they will be created indefinitely as long as the page is open

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', id);
  if (color === undefined) {
    let colors = ['#35def2', '#35f242', '#b2f235', '#f2ad35', '#f24735', '#3554f2', '#8535f2', '#eb35f2', '#f2359b', '#f23547'];
    div.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }
  else {
   div.style.backgroundColor = color; 
  }
  div.classList.add("circle");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function ontimeOut(){
    createDiv("div-" + Math.random());
    setTimeout(ontimeOut, 3000);
}
ontimeOut();
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` as mentioned, but you need to make sure to clear the interval as well `clearInterval(createWithTimer);` otherwise you will end up with an infinite loop.

To avoid possible repetition of colors, you can splice the current value `colors.splice(circleCounter,1)` in each loop from the colors array. If you don't know how many circles you will/want to create you can specify the amount and create a 6 digit hex value on the fly: `hex => [...Array(6)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('');`

If you want to reuse this snippet, you simply wrap it in a function and call it when needed: `generateCircles(10, 1000);` with the 1st parameter being the amount of circles you want and the 2nd parameter the interval time between the creation of each circle.

You can also probably set the background as follow:
`div.style.backgroundColor = color || colors[randomNumber];`

```js
function createDiv(id, color) {
  
  const div = document.createElement('div'),
  createHex = hex => [...Array(6)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('');
  
  div.id = `circle-${id+1}`;
  div.className += "circle";
  div.style.backgroundColor = color || `#${createHex()}`,  
    
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  
}

function generateCircles(amountofCircles, interValTimer){
  
  let circleCounter = 0;
    
  let createWithTimer = setInterval(()=>{
    if(circleCounter >= amountofCircles)
      clearInterval(createWithTimer);
    else 
      createDiv(circleCounter);

    circleCounter++;

  }, interValTimer);
  
}

generateCircles(10, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```